# Add "Row Number" to list component in react-admin Datagrid

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, react-admin

My id primary key field type is UUID and I want to add one human friendly **Row Number** to my `<Datagrid />` component.
How we can do this?
I see that we can create custom components like this:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#writing-your-own-field-component

Maybe we can create new field type like `<RowNumber />` but when I see above link it seems it's only have `source` and `record`.

How we can get `index` number of a row in my custom field?

Comment: I think this would be really strange. Consider what would happen when the sorting or filtering changes. What would you expect the row numbers to be?

Comment: It's just a row number. I don't want to sort with this. It's just in presentation layer as a human friendly column.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. If you have two other columns (`firstName` and `lastName` for example) and the user sort by `firstName` then change their mind and sort by `lastName`, what do you expect the row numbers to be in both cases?

Comment: @GildasGarcia I think what b24 says is a number that is completely unrelated to the data and data sorting, like the record number in a datasheet

Comment: @b24 did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem and got this way of solving it.

First all, I've created a `DataGridWithIndex` component that has the same  signature as the [original DataGrid](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/list/datagrid/Datagrid.tsx)

```
import React, { FC, useMemo } from 'react';
import { DatagridProps, useListContext, useRecordContext, Datagrid } from 'react-admin';

export const CurrentIndexField = (props: any) => {
  const record = useRecordContext(props);
  return record && record.__index__ !== undefined ? <span>{record.__index__} </span> : <span></span>;
};

export const DataGridWithIndex: FC<DatagridProps> = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { children, ...rest } = props;
  const { data: rawData } = useListContext();
  const data = useMemo(() => rawData?.map((dt, index) => ({ ...dt, __index__: index + 1 /* make it 1-based */ })) || [], [rawData]);
  return (
    <Datagrid {...rest} ref={ref} data={data}>
      <CurrentIndexField />
      {children}
    </Datagrid>
  );
});
```

Now that we have it, we can just use:

```
 ...
    <List /* whatever params here */>
      <DataGridWithIndex /* whatever params here */>
          <TextField source="title" />
          ...
      </DataGridWithIndex>
    </List>
```

Note that the index is per-page: if you paginate and are in page (say) 4, the first row on the page, will have index=1 (and not 41). That is OK for my requirements.